# Less CSS - Add vendor prefixes with less.js in development environment

Tags: css, less, vendor-prefix

I'm using [LESS](http://lesscss.org/) with [Gulp](http://gulpjs.com/). I'm also using the [Autoprefixer plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-autoprefixer) which adds all needed vendor prefixes based on [Browserlist](https://www.npmjs.com/package/browser-list). This works pretty nice when creating all minified files for the final export.

My problem is: When I test the CSS in the developement environment using *less.js* there are no vendor prefixes added. It seems that the auto prefixer is only available for the cli. **Is there a way to add vendor prefixes on the fly with *less.js* or another plug in?** I've already tried to run [prefixfree](http://lea.verou.me/prefixfree/) after *less.js* but without luck.

Comment: I'd recommend to compile LESS with Gulp for development as well (watch the .less files for changes, recompile + autoprefix automatically, live reload the page). This way you run your dev without the less.js overhead and compiled with the same version of LESS that will go to production.

Comment: @pawel I think I'll go with this solution. Maybe it's good to remove the overhead from less.js even in development. Could you post that as an answer?

Answer (score 0):

Just pipe a stream from `gulp-less` to autoprefixer, e.g.

```
gulp.task('styles', [], function () {
    return gulp.src('less/*.less')
        .pipe(gulplLss())
        .pipe(postcss([autoprefixer()]))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('css/'));
}

gulp.task('watch', function () {
    gulp.watch('less/*.less', 'styles');
}
```

(This is using autoprefixer via `postcss` tool which is now recommended way. Before deprecation it the autoprefixer line whould be: `.pipe(autoprefixer())`)

Comment: I actually use it like this: `var plugins = [autoprefix, cleancss];` and then `gulp.pipe(less({ plugins: plugins }))`. Is this wrong or deprecated the way I'm doing it, because it works fine currently. :)

Comment: Oh, I actually didn't know that one. I'd still prefer to use one gulp plugin for one job, it gives more controll over what's happening. As it seems :)

Answer (score 0):

There is a pure frontend solution (if it is what you are looking for). Autoprefixer can run in browser environment. You don't have to run it as a Less plugin.

In [estFiddle](http://ecomfe.github.io/est/fiddle/) I run Autoprefixer after compiling Less into CSS and it works. (You can see source code [here](https://github.com/ecomfe/est/blob/gh-pages/fiddle/js/app.js#L316).)